# multiply xml for single activity

Tags: xml, button, android-activity, position

I have 1 activity that for diffrent input need to make change on the location of buttons on its XML file.
I try to do it by using setX to diffrent position but it didn't move.
I was thinking maybe to make several XML where have the some data include button ID and the only diffrent will be there position on the screen. But then I need to attach diffrent XML for the some activity.Is it possible and how this can be done?
Thanks a lot
Bar.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong with the code that don't move my image on the layout. So this is much easier than make several layouts.
If we want to change position of the image by setX(number), we have first to make a call of its parameters.

So it go this way:

1. imageviewLeft.requestLayout(); // get its size parameters
2. imageviewLeft.setX(number);

And then it calculates the right new position.

Remember that number units is pixel and can't express in dp,sp ect.

So to help translate from dp to px we can use this code:

```
private int dp2px(int dp) {
    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int pixels = (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
    return pixels;
}
```